# Prove that the eigenvectors of this matrix are a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that, $w_i>0$ and $a_{i,j} = w_i / w_j$ for all $i,j=1,\dots,n$.

Note that from the construction comes that $\operatorname{rank} A=1$.

Prove that the eigenvectors of $A$ are a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or equivalently prove that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: More precisely, one ought to say something like, "Prove that $\mathbb{R}^n$ admits a basis of eigenvectors of $A$"---the set of eigenvectors of $A$ is infinite and hence never forms a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your matrix can be written as product of a column matrix and a row matrix:
$$
  A=\pmatrix{w_1\\w_2\\\vdots\\w_n}\pmatrix{1/w_1&1/w_2&\ldots&1/w_n},
$$
which explains why it has rank$~1$ (provided that $n>0$; the case $n=0$ is trivial and I will henceforth not consider it). Now as you can for instance read in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/596027/18880), such a matrix is diagonalisable if and only if it has nonzero trace (the part that the condition is sufficient is easy: due to the rank, eigenvalue $0$ already has geometric multiplicity $n-1$, and there must be a nonzero eigenvalue because of, and equal to, the trace). Here the diagonal entries are all$~1$, so the trace is $n\neq0$ and $A$ is diagonalisable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start -- perhaps you can fill in the details:

We have $w = (w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ with every entry positive. Let $v = (\frac{1}{w_1},\ldots,\frac{1}{w_n})$, inverting each entry. Observe that, as a linear transformation, $A$ is given by $A(x) = (x \cdot v) w$, where "$\cdot$" is the Euclidean dot product.

- Find the kernel of $A$ and its dimension.
- Find the eigenspace of $\lambda=n$ and its dimension.

Comment: Actually, I think there is a shorter argument: once you have guaranteed that there is a nonzero eigenvalue, it automatically has an eigenspace of positive dimension. So now you have one eigenvector with a nonzero eigenvalue and $n-1$ of them with the zero eigenvalue, so you're done.

Comment: @Ian: I don't disagree with you, but I think I will leave this hint as is. Nice to know we have a (rank-1) projection.

Comment: There is no eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ (unless $n=1$).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Oops! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Ian: By Marc's comment, I should have actually said "n times a rank-1 projection".