# Determinant of $(I+uv^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $u,v \in R^n$, How can I find $det(I+uv^*)$? This problem was given as preparatory for final exam and I dont know how to approach it. I dont see some nice ways to express this determinant. This is from Numerical Linear algebra course. Could you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is an invertible square matrix and $u$, $v$ are column vectors. Then the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) states that
$$
{\displaystyle \det \left({A} +{uv} ^{\textsf {T}}\right)
=\left(1+{v} ^{\textsf {T}}{A} ^{-1}{u} \right)\,\det \left({A} \right)\,.}
$$

In your case, let $A=I$.

The proof is essentially based on the following observation:
$$
{\displaystyle {\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf {I} &0\\\mathbf {v} ^{\textsf {T}}&1\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf {I} +\mathbf {uv} ^{\textsf {T}}&\mathbf {u} \\0&1\end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf {I} &0\\-\mathbf {v} ^{\textsf {T}}&1\end{pmatrix}}={\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf {I} &\mathbf {u} \\0&1+\mathbf {v} ^{\textsf {T}}\mathbf {u} \end{pmatrix}}.}
$$

---

[Added later:]
Alternatively, in the nontrivial case when both $u$ and $v$ are nonzero vecotrs and $n>1$, note that $B:={uv} ^{\textsf {T}}$ is a rank one matrix. Moreover, $\lambda = {v} ^{\textsf {T}}u$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ since:
$$Bu = (uv^T)u=u(v^Tu)=(v^Tu)u.$$ Since $B$ is of rank one, $0$ must be an eigenvalue as well. It is not difficult to show<sup>1</sup> that $0$ has multiplicity $n-1$. So the matrix $B$ is similar to an upper triangle matrix with the diagonal:
$$
(v^Tu,0,\cdots,0).
$$
It follows that the matrix $I+B$ is similar to an upper triangle matrix with the diagonal:
$$
(1+v^Tu,1,\cdots,1).
$$
But similar matrices has the same determinant. So you have the same result as in the matrix determinant lemma.

<sup>1</sup>Note: see also answers to this question: [Eigenvalues of the rank one matrix $uv^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55165/587192)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming $uv^*\ne0$, then $u$ is an eigenvector, as $(uv^*)u=(v^*u)u$. Since the matrix has rank $1$, the characteristic polynomial is $\det(uv^*-XI)=(v^*u-X)(0-X)^{n-1}$. Evaluating this at $X=-1$ yields
$$
\det(uv^*+I)=v^*u+1
$$

Comment: Very clever short proof.

Comment: @JeanMarie And the general formula for $\det(A+uv^*)$ follows in the same fashion, because $A^{-1}u$ is an eigenvector of $A^{-1}uv^*$ (which has rank at most $1$) relative to $v^*A^{-1}u$.

Comment: > "Since the matrix has rank $1$, the characteristic polynomial is $\det(uv^*-XI)=(v^*u-X)(0-X)^{n-1}$."

Why is this true?

Comment: @JohnD The geometric multiplicity of $0$ is $n-1$, so the algebraic multiplicity must be at least $n-1$, but it cannot be greater because of the nonzero eigenvalue, so it is $n-1$.

Comment: I understand uv* is rank 1 and that XI is full rank, how do we know we can say anything about their difference? And how do we know their difference has eigenvalues v*u - X and -X? Why do we have linearity in the eigenvalues of this new difference matrix?

Comment: @JohnD You're looking from the wrong perspective. By definition, the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$ is $\det(A-XI)$, where $X$ is an indeterminate considered as a scalar. We know that we can factor the characteristic polynomial as $(\lambda_1-X)^{m_1}\dotsm(\lambda_r-X)^{m_r}$, where $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r$ are the distinct eigenvalues (in the complex numbers). The dimension $d_k$ of the eigenspace relative to $\lambda_k$ satisfies $d_k\le m_k$. Here $r=2$, $\lambda_1=v^*u$ with $m_1\ge1$ and $\lambda_2=0$ with $d_2=n-1$. The only possibility for $m_2$ is $n-1$, and $m_1=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily convince yourself that one eigenvector is $u$ with eigenvalue $1+v^* u$ and the remaining eigenvalues are 1 (with the eigenspace given by all the vectors $w$ with $v^*w=0$). Thus the determinant is given by $$1+v^*u\,.$$