# Is it possible for a $3 \times 3$ matrix to have rank 1 but not be diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Is it possible for a $3 \times 3$ matrix to have rank $1$ but not be diagonalizable?

If the matrix only has the top left entry, then obviously it is already diagonal. But what about other two entries? I know that a condition for the matrix to be diagonalizable is for the matrix to have $3$ linearly independent eigenvectors, but I am unsure how to prove whether that will always be the case for any rank $1$, $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix of rank $1$ that isn't diagonalisable.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55165/eigenvalues-of-the-rank-one-matrix-uvt) might help!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Then it follows that $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable, correct? (Since there is only one eigenvector)

Comment: @SolidSnackDrive That's not a square matrix, so cannot be diagonalisable.

Comment: Sorry, please see my edit.