# Find the eigenvalue of $I-\tau uv^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

Suppose that $\tau \neq 0$，and vector $u\neq 0,v\neq 0\in R^n$, I want to find the eigenvalues of the matrix $E(u,v,\tau)=I-\tau uv^T$,here both $u$ and $v$ are column vectors,I have shown that $\lambda I-I-\tau uv^T=(\lambda -1)I-\tau uv^T$ and I need to show the principal minors of the matrix $\tau uv^T$ but I don't know how to calculate the higher order principal minors of thie matrix

Comment: calculate the eigenvalues directly. Assuming $u,v$  are not dependent, given a vector $w$  that is orthogonal to $u,v,$  the result $Ew$ is especially simple. There are two more eigenvalues, one direction is $u,$  so what is $Eu?$ If you like, take unit $u/ |u| $  and then a perpendicular vector in the $u,v$ plane

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55165/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concentrate on the matrix ${uv}^T$, if $w$ is any vector perpendicular to $v$ (these belong to an $(n-1)$ dimensional space), then $ {uv}^T w = 0$, and if $w$ is along $u$ then ${uv}^T w = (u^T v) u $, thus $u v^T$ has $(n-1)$ zero eigenvalues, and $1$ eigenvalue of $ u^T v $.  Therefore, the eigenvalues of $(I - \tau u v^T)$ are $(n-1)$ eigenvalues each being equal to $1$, and one eigenvalue equal to $(1 - \tau (u^T v)) $