# How to find the eingenvalues of matrix $M$ with $\text{rank}(M)\leqslant1\;?$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, trace

If a $\,n\times n\,$ matrix $M$ satisfies

$\text{Rank}(M)\leqslant1\;,\;$ then $\;\det(I+tM)=1+t\text{Tr}(M)\;,$
where $\;\text{Tr}(M)\;$ denotes the trace of $\,M$.

In this book it is stated that all eigenvalues of $M$ are zero except a single eigenvalue $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}.$ But I don't know why.
I would appreciate your collaboration.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Yes, the eigenvalue $0$ then has multiplicity at least $n-1$, see the duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eigenvalues of the rank one matrix $uv^T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55165/eigenvalues-of-the-rank-one-matrix-uvt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deal the problem case wise.
Case 1:Rank M=0. Then M =0. So all eigenvalues are zero.
Case 2: Rank M =1. Then M =$AA^T$ where A is a column vector. The eigenvalues are then 0 repeated n-1 times and $A^TA$. Thus all n eigenvalues are determined.