# How to compute all powers $A^n$ and find is the matrix of $A$ diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

$V$ is a complex vector space with basis $\left\{e_{1},e_{2}\right\}$. Consider the linear operator on $V$ defined by $A\left( e_{1}\right)=ie_{1},A\left( e_{2}\right)=-ie_{1}, a\neq 0$. Compute all powers $A^{n}, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and find their matrices. Is there a basis of $V$ so that the matrix of $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: See the question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/991346 (Matrices of rank 1) for an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rank $A = 1$ you can check that $A^2 = \text{tr} A\times A = iA
$
hence via induction:
$$
A^n = i^{n-1} A
$$

Finally, as we already have an eigenvector the last part is seay: in the basis $(e_1, e_1 + e_2$ the matrix of $A$ is 
\begin{pmatrix}
  i &0 \\
  0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: What does "trA" mean?

Comment: it is the trace is $A$.

Comment: Is there a basis of $V$ so that the matrix of $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: @Leo look at the end of my message. doesn't it answer your question?

Comment: Oh... Sorry! :)